# in my code its only printing only last page data in excel

Tags: java, selenium

Here I am fetching all the data for each company for each page. In my excel only last page data printing.

```
    public class DemoTest {
            WebDriver driver;
            File file = new File("D:\\output1.xlsx");
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sh = wb.createSheet("First Sheet");
    
            @BeforeClass
            public void setUp() {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://Selenium-java//driver//driver1//chromedriver.exe");
              driver = new ChromeDriver();
              driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
             driver.get("https://cmmiinstitute.com/pars/?StateId=abc1277f-07c4-449f-b75d-b9725234cf0e&PageNumber=1");
                
            }
            
            @Test(priority=1)
//looking for india data
            public void verifyCountry() throws InterruptedException {
                Select drpcounrtry = new Select (driver.findElement(By.name("Filters.CountryIsoCode")));
                drpcounrtry.selectByVisibleText("India");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='APPLY']")).click();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            @Test(priority=2)
            public void fetchdata() throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException {
                
                int o=1;
                
                while(o<=106) {
                    
                    WebElement next =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Next']"));
                    next.click()
//click on next to go next page
                    java.util.List<WebElement> companyname1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/h3/a/div"));
                     for (int i=0;i<companyname1.size();i++) {
                        
                             sh.createRow(i).createCell(1).setCellValue(companyname1.get(i).getText()); 
                            
                    }
                    ////
                    java.util.List<WebElement> appraisalleader1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/small"));
                     for (int j=0;j<appraisalleader1.size();j++) {
                         sh.getRow(j).createCell(2).setCellValue(appraisalleader1.get(j).getText()); 
                }
                    ///
                    java.util.List<WebElement> partner1  = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/small"));
                     for (int k=0;k<partner1.size();k++) {
                         sh.getRow(k).createCell(3).setCellValue(partner1.get(k).getText()); 
                }
                    ////
                    java.util.List<WebElement> validity1  = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/small"));
                     for (int l=0;l<validity1.size();l++) {
                         sh.getRow(l).createCell(4).setCellValue(validity1.get(l).getText()); 
                }
                    ////
                    java.util.List<WebElement> sponser1= driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/small"));
                    
                         for (int m=0;m<sponser1.size();m++) {
                             sh.getRow(m).createCell(5).setCellValue(sponser1.get(m).getText()); 
                    }
                    o++;
                }
                
                try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                
                    wb.write(fos);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

First I am fetching company name starting from page 2. Then appraisalleader so on. But in my output only last page data printing.

Comment: Where is this fos declared?

Comment: I'd guess it's a lack of webdriver waits, checking for stale elements... do you get any exceptions when calling getText()?  (Try/catch it and post exceptions if any)

Comment: No.. Pcalkins... Its not giving any exception

Comment: Updated row is overridden over and over again till the loop ends. that is why you are seeing one result at the end. in the while loop you are always getting the 0th row. please use the int o inside the creating part. there is the method called, getLastRow in the sheet. use that for add entries after that

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new row in your loop

```
Row newRow = sheet.createRow(yourCount before loop + sheet.getLastRowNum());
```